# Introductory html, css, javascript online course

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone recommend an introductory online course for the basics of html, css and javascript?

It's for my son's International Baccalaureat course and the requirements appear to be pretty basic - e.g. draw a form and button, take some input from the form, do a simple calculation, output the result.

They'll also need to do a bit of array pushing and popping at some point, I think.

Unfortunately, the course isn't being presented in a way that suits my son, and I was hoping to find something simple, well structured and pedagogic. Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/ 
Is pretty much first year of college in the Netherlands haha.

Comment: @A.bakker You should turn that into an answer, since it's probably the correct place to go in any case.

Comment: @BenI. will do, but with some more info haha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that you should use [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/) it nicely covers the basics of HTML, CSS, JavaScript and a few other related things(I would really suggest looking at MySQL/PHP if you want to go in to web development what is also offered there).

It's pretty much inline with the first half year/year of a web development college degree in the Netherlands.

I always advise my students to follow the course next to their regular classes (I don't teach HTML/CSS/JavaScript myself) seeing it gives a good explanation, a nice try it yourself editor and covers things that they sadly don't get during their regular classes.

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes that looks perfect - well structured and simply written :)

Comment: Really? The w3schools company has a pretty bad reputation in the JS community, which even led to the launch of https://www.w3fools.com. They improved, but their documentation is still lacking, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is a much better resource.

Comment: @Bergi from what I have seen as a sort of teacher, the students find MDN a bit overwhelming as beginners. W3Schools is, a bit more beginner friendly up to the point that high-schoolers seem to be able to follow it with relative ease.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML

Comment: Thanks for the help - yes the site looks like a good "fit"

Answer (score 2):

Trying to keep up with web development is hard. Every year there are new tools , new frameworks, new way to do things. But surprisingly I find the following Dinosaurs serials Peter Jang wrote in 2017 & 2018 are still the best materials I would recommend to the new comers. To me it is quite insane that what he wrote in 2017/2018 still stands in 2023.

1. ["Modern JavaScript Explained For Dinosaurs"](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/modern-javascript-explained-for-dinosaurs-f695e9747b70) mainly focus on the tools (including nodejs) used front end development. I can't find any other articles to better explain tools used in front end. For example, even the [webpack official document](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) lacks of good explanation of what module bundler is, why use it, or why use it with babel.
2. ["Modern HTML Explained For Dinosaurs"](https://medium.com/actualize-network/modern-html-explained-for-dinosaurs-65e56af2981) is the longest article among this serial (it says 34 minutes to read but it probably takes longer to read it though)
3. ["Modern CSS Explained For Dinosaurs"](https://medium.com/actualize-network/modern-css-explained-for-dinosaurs-5226febe3525). From my own experience web developer often overlook the importance of css.

I know the question was asked about online course but I have not found a good course to cover them all and up to day.If you are new to web development this serial may take couple of days to digest as you may further google the terms mentioned in the articles. Only after that I would then recommend to learn the framework like react/vue/angular.

If you want to learn the modern javascript I would recommend https://javascript.info/